# How should I declare attributes in JS class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I am currently working on an API and I want to create classes, one class `Object` that retrieves data from tables and a class associated with a table. I'm trying to create a attribute in the `Object` class which is set while calling the static method `get()` from a class associated with a table. How should I use the attributes ?

My API is running with express, I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, I'm using ObjectionJS as my ORM, I also use Knex. I have a `loader.js` file which requires all my model files.

Object.js:

```js
'use strict';

const dbTables = require('../../src/database/Models/loader');

module.exports = class Object {


    constructor () {
        console.log('Test');
    }

    //Get queries

    static get() {
        console.log(`ModelName = ${this.modelName}`);
        const req = 'dbTables.' + this.modelName + '.query()';
        return eval(req);
    }
}
```

UserClass.js:

```js
'use strict';

const Object = require('./Object');

module.exports = class UserClass extends Object {

    constructor() {
        super('Employee');
        this.modelName = 'Employee';
    }
};
```

Here is the error I'm getting :

```
ModelName = undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at eval (eval at get (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/src/Classes/Object.js:17:16), <anonymous>:1:20)
    at Function.get (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/src/Classes/Object.js:17:16)
    at app.get (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/index.js:54:28)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at methodOverride (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/method-override/index.js:65:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/usersio/SafiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: theres no need for `eval` here.

Comment: typescript can be your friend to try to help enforce things.

Comment: `Object` isn't a reserved keyword on javascript but already defined. You should consider to find another name.

Comment: I tried renaming the `Object` class into `ObjectClass` but it still doesn't work. I think I'll try using Typescript

Comment: The name wasn't the problem, just a quick note about think to avoid. your problem is caused by the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because your function `get()` is static and you're trying to get `this.modelName` on it. 
But static functions do not ref to a particular instance of it.

Let's look at some examples:

```js
const dbTables = {
  Employee: {query : () => ['1', '2', '3']},
  Car: {query : () => ['A', 'B', 'C']},
}

class AbstractTable {
    //Get queries
    static get() {
        console.log(`get():`, {this:this, model: this.modelName});
        return dbTables[this.modelName] 
            && dbTables[this.modelName].query() 
            || null;
    }
    
    // Same but non static
    getNonStatic() {
        console.log(`getNonStatic():`, {this:this, model: this.modelName});
        return dbTables[this.modelName] 
            && dbTables[this.modelName].query() 
            || null;
    }
    
    // Static with args
    static getWithArg(table) {
    
        console.log(`getWithArg(table):`, {this:this, model: table.modelName, table:table});
        return dbTables[table.modelName] 
            && dbTables[table.modelName].query() 
            || null;
    }
}
class UserTable extends AbstractTable {

    constructor() {
        super('Employee');
        this.modelName = 'Employee';
    }
};

console.log("--- Test 1 ---");
console.log(UserTable.get()); // get() is static so NO instance (this is undefined)


console.log("--- Test 2 ---");
// Create an instance of UserTable: 
const userTable = new UserTable();
console.log("Function:", userTable.get); // This is not defined because get() is static  


console.log("--- Test 3 ---");
console.log("Function:", userTable.getNonStatic); 
console.log("Result:", userTable.getNonStatic()); // This is not defined because get() is static  


console.log("--- Test 4 ---");
// you can also use static and inject the UserTable
console.log("Function:", AbstractTable.getWithArg(userTable));
```

You can also redefined an abstract static function and use it using `super()`

```js
const dbTables = {
  Employee: {query : () => ['1', '2', '3']},
  Car: {query : () => ['A', 'B', 'C']},
}

class AbstractTable {
    //Get queries
    static get(modelName) {
        return dbTables[modelName] 
            && dbTables[modelName].query() 
            || null;
    }
}

class UserTable extends AbstractTable {
  static get() {
    return super.get("Employee");
  }
}

console.log(UserTable.get());
```

Comment: But you have much more details about the backgrounds.

Comment: I tried this but I still can't declare the attribute in the `UserClass`, getting an error from the '=' : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Comment: Ok I got it to work. I used the `super.get()` and made both `get()` functions static in both classes. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are called when you create an instance of a class.

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    console.log('ctor called');
  }
}

const instance = new Test();
// will log 'ctor called'
```

When you call a static method, you do not create an instance and your constructor is not called. That's the first reason why `this.modelName` in your get() function is undefined and so you are trying to call `query()` on something that does not exist.

Try `console.log(req)` in your get() function.

Second reason is that `this` in your constructor refers to the instance while `this` in a static method refers to the class.

One option would be to add a static property to your extending class and set the model name there.

```js
const dbTables = {
  Employee: {query : () => ['1', '2', '3']},
}

/*module.exports =*/ class Object {
    //Get queries
    static get() {
        return dbTables[this.modelName].query();
    }
}

/*module.exports =*/ class UserClass extends Object {
    static modelName = 'Employee';
};

const queryResult = UserClass.get();
console.log("Users: ", queryResult);
```

Comment: Even better answer than mine.

Comment: Seems logic to me but I can't declare the attribute `modelName` in UserClass
I get this error :
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
`

Comment: Now I'm lost. I'm a TypeScript user and tested my examples with Chrome and as far as I can see, nodejs should support all features.